# How to find date using day number of the year in VBA?

Tags: vba, forms, excel

Suppose If i enter 209. It has to give me Jul 28th.
I could get day number from the date but in reverse. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be this code will help you

```
Sub Test()
Dim x
x = 209

MsgBox DateAdd("d", x - 1, "2018/1/1")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the number of days to the last day of last year.

```
=209 +"12/31/2017"
```

Comment: that's a string isn't it?

Comment: Yes and Excel will change it to a date.

Answer (score 0):

The following

```
=DATE(2018,1,209)
```

You can format in different ways the date returned e.g.

```
=TEXT(DATE(2018,1,209),"Mmm dd yyyy")
```

---

**VBA and UDF:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Debug.Print GetDate(209)
End Sub

Public Function GetDate(ByVal daynumber As Long) As String
     GetDate = Format$(DateSerial(Year(Date), 1, daynumber), "Mmm dd yyyy")
End Function
```

Comment: I only know the day number and year not the month.

Comment: You are right, it is working in cell, not in vba. It says syntax error.

Comment: that is kind of you